# не корректно работает pyinstaller

Tags: python

Использую pyinstaller для создания exe. Нормально работал, сейчас сделал инстаграм-бота и попробовал сделать из него exe-шник, все как обычно создает, папку distr, все такое, но почему то вместо файла insta-bot.exe я получаю insta-bot.manifest и какой то зип-архив в папке build, в cmd использую команду pyinstaller -F insta-bot.py

Как эту ситуацию можно исправить и с чем она связана?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы создался EXE-файл, нужно выполнить следующую команду:

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

Если приложение графическое:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --windowed file.py
```

Так же у `PyInstaller` могут возникать проблемы из-за кэширования результатов предыдущей сборки. Решается это добавлением опции `--clear`.

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: @Rus говорить "не работает" - плохая практика. Нужны подробности.